# How to add localhost(127.0.0.1) rules in routing table?

Tags: routing, localhost, tomcat

superusers.

I have two NICs with connected to  different networks.

what I did :

```
route delete *
route add 0.0.0.0    mask 0.0.0.0          172.16.15.254 METRIC 266 IF 11
route add 10.201.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0    10.201.15.254 IF 13
route add 127.0.0.0  mask 255.0.0.0        0.0.0.0 metric 1 IF 1
route add 127.0.0.1  mask 255.255.255.255  0.0.0.0 metric 1 IF 1
```

those two networks work well, but my localhost doesn't (when I run tomcat in my PC)

pinging 127.0.0.1 results "General Failure"

what can I do to fix this? I really need to run the local server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have a route to the loopback address. If you delete that you will be able to ping 127.0.0.1

Comment: if you look at the routing table... the localhost/127.0.0.1 is there... and you can ping it... if you clear the routeing table (route -f)... you cannot pint 127.0.0.1 anymore untill you add it again--- soooooo.... ;-)